# Calculating velocity of sinking aphere

Tags: matlab, physics

A spherical particle with Diameter of 5mm  and  relative density delta=1.5 is sinking in water. I need to calculate its velocity.
I was tasked with first building a function that given "Ryenolds number" returns the Drag force be given estimations.
This is what I did:

```
function [cd]=dragg(re)
if re<1 
    cd=24/re;
elseif re>=1 & re<600 
    cd=18.5/(re^(3/5));
else re>=600 & re<2*10^5
    cd=0.44;
end

re = logspace(-1,5,100);
for i = 1:100
    xv(i) = dragg(re(i));
end
loglog(re,xv)
```

Now I need to calculate its velocity with the given relations:

[image]

Where u=velocity, V=volume, A=cross section Area.
The first and second equations is the sum of forces, and the third is for spherical particle.

So I want to build a function of sum of forces to velocity, and the velocity I'm looking for will be the root of this equation. But I don't know how. It looks like the sum of forces will be 0 only when u will be infinite.
Any ideas? corrections? 
I'm new with matlab so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Start with equation 2:

g(rho<sub>z</sub> - rho)V<sub>B</sub> = (1/2) C<sub>D</sub> rho u<sup>2</sup> A<sub>ƒ</sub>

You *could* try to solve this for C<sub>D</sub>, but I don't see why you'd want to. Instead, solve for u:

u = sqrt[ 2g(rho<sub>z</sub> - rho)V<sub>B</sub>/(C<sub>D</sub> rho A<sub>ƒ</sub>) ]